# How to change characters in a list to hex numbers?

Tags: python, list, hex

```
key = input()

a = list(str(key))
print(a)
```

Does anyone know how to change that `a` list to get hex numbers in there? Example:

```
key = "abc"
>> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

But instead of those letters hex numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: I actually was trying with some of it, but i need the whole list to be in hex.

Comment: So your question is not how to convert a character to its hex value but how to parse a list?

Comment: Yeah, exacly, i think.

Comment: The question covers that.  You can convert the whole string without converting to a list.  BTW, just to be snarky, "a", "b", and "c" ARE hex numbers.  That's why you should SHOW us exactly what output you want.

Comment: what output do you want **exactly**? "Hex numbers" is ambiguous, you at the very least need to specify the *type* of object. Do you want `int` objects corresponding to the hex value a, b, c? Do you want `str` objects in some other format? Please be *precise*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to get the int representation of a character, and [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) to get the hex representation of that int.

```
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in "abc"]
['0x61', '0x62', '0x63']
```